# After updating Laravel composer blank page coming

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I added in google mapper require in composer.json and updated it successfully. But when trying to connect my page. Just seeing a blank page. No error or something. just a blank page.

this is the log.

> Package operations: 1 install, 2 updates, 0 removals
>     - Updating laravel/framework (v5.7.10 => v5.7.11): Downloading (100%)
>     - Updating spatie/laravel-backup (5.11.1 => 5.11.2): Downloading (100%)
>     - Installing cornford/googlmapper (v2.33.0): Downloading (100%)          Writing lock file Generating optimized autoload files
>
> > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> >     @php artisan package:discover Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server Discovered Package:
> >     cornford/googlmapper Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy Discovered
> >     Package: kyslik/column-sortable Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
> >     Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon Discovered Package:
> >     nunomaduro/collision Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-backup Package
> >     manifest generated successfully.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Do you see anything when you view the page source, or errors in the javascript console? Is anything showing up in your webserver error logs, php error logs, or laravel error logs?

Comment: @TravisBritz No, console and source are empty.

Comment: Does everything return to normal if you remove the same package again, or does it still persist?

Comment: @TravisBritz I deleted the package and updated again. but no change.

Comment: @Potti Which laravel version and PHP Version you have?

Comment: Can you look at your laravel logs in `storage/logs/`? Are these empty too? Pages without a source mostly mean an error was thrown.